# Error 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9' when I insert data item

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-8

I have two data items :

1)

```
sum(If ([DEV].[STATUS] IN ('Success','Failure'))
THEN ([DEV.[AMT])
ELSE (0))
```

2)

```
sum(If ([DEV].[STATUS] IN ('Success','Failure'))
THEN (1)
ELSE (0))
```

When I try to use the first item in a list cell I get an error 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9' / group function is not allowed here

The second is working fine in the same scenario.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why are your aggregate and aggregate rollup functions set to none?  Pull the sum out of your query item, and set the aggregate to sum.

Comment: Andrew, I tried setting the aggregate function to none, summarize, total, automatic...but its still not working.

Comment: Are you trying to use this query item in a filter?

Comment: No...I have created a list..I am trying to insert it into one of list cells

Comment: I have tried the following to GO Data Warehouse (Query) model and it worked OK: sum(If ([Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type] IN ('E-mail', 'Fax'))
THEN ([Sales (query)].[Sales fact].[Quantity])
ELSE (0)) Does the report validate OK? If so do you have any other query subjects that might do problems? Is the [DEV].[AMT} data type is int or float? or maybe its charcter type?

Comment: [DEV].[AMT] is of float type. The same thing seems to work in another report but not this one. not sure why I am getting the group function not allowed here error

Comment: Did you make any specific changes in properties? When I try to sum up the number 1 it works but not when I try to sum up [DEV].[AMT]

Answer (score 0):

I set the aggregate function to none. The problem was in my structure. I was adding the data item to list cell under list footer. When I added the item to list cell under list page footer, I was able to run the report successfully.